# How to stop the repeated job scheduler manually in Quartz?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have written scheduler jobs to take reports in Quartz.  I'm getting exceptions such as the one below whenever I try to take the new report:

> "Two repeated jobs are already running"

It won't allow me to start the scheduler. Some of the existing schedules are running repeatedly.  How can I find that particular scheduler and stop it in Quartz?